Nestjs can’t generate
enter image description here
I have this error on github codespaces and my local machine(windows 11).
Node version is 20
Package.json as nest new default.
Every this default from nestcli except elsinore file. I add prettier rule.
I want to generate nestjs module.

Please add enough (relevant) code to create a [mre] inside the question, furthermore please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

this is a bug with typescript 5.5.4
Downgrade it to 5.5.3 and you should be fine
Also, come on, isn't that hard to check out github issues. See: https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/2662
